# Self sizing cell just doesn't work for me

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I tried to follow the WWCD 2014 session 226, which introduced the way to realize self sizing cells in iOS 8 using auto layout, and it just doesn't work as it should.



HHTableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HHTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic)UILabel *title;

@end
```

HHTableViewCell.m

```
#import "HHTableViewCell.h"

@implementation HHTableViewCell

@synthesize title = _title;

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure control(s)

#pragma mark -- title Lable
        _title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 15.0, 0.0)];
        _title.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline];
        _title.numberOfLines = 0;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_title];


#pragma mark -- constraints
        NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        UIView *contentView = self.contentView;

        [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:_title
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:contentView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.8
                                constant:3.0]];

        [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:_title
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:contentView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.8
                                constant:3.0]];

        [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:_title
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeFirstBaseline
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:contentView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                multiplier:1.8
                                constant:3.0]];

        [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:contentView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                toItem:nil
                                attribute:0
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:44.0]];

        [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[_title]-15-|"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:nil
                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_title)]];



        [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
    }
    return self;

}

@end
```

MMTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MMTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

MMTableViewController.m

```
#import "MMTableViewController.h"
#import "HHTableViewCell.h"

@interface MMTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MMTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[HHTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HiCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[HHTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HCell"];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 10;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"HiCell";

    HHTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.title.text = @"Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. ";

    // Configure the cell...
    NSLog(cell.title.text);

    return cell;
}


@end
```

The cell is of fixed height and wrapping two lines of text. Looks like this:


**Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello**

**Aplle. Hello Apple. Hello Apple. Hello Apple...**



Constraints and subviews are added programatically.
Simulator is running iOS 8.3 in Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: you shouldn't use pragma marks inside methods. That just doesn't look good and its really not intended to be used in that way. Use it to group multiple methods

Comment: not that familiar to the use of pragma marks. code above is just a "copy" of  WWDC 2014 session 226, part of it may be missing, so i don't know if I'm using it the right way. thank you for the advice.

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but you should be setting title's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
property to NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UILabel to work with constraints, looking at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth), I think you need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property:

> This property affects the size of the label when layout constraints
>   are applied to it. During layout, if the text extends beyond the width
>   specified by this property, the additional text is flowed to one or
>   more new lines, thereby increasing the height of the label.

However, unless you want some specific cell customization, you can use the default UITableViewCell, and set `numberOfLines = 0` on the provided `titleLabel`.  It will work with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, although I've only tested it in conjunction with `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

**UPDATE**:

From what I've learned, you also need to set `estimatedRowHeight` to something in the `viewDidLoad` (the value doesn't even needs to be accurate/important it seems).

[Here is a working example](https://gist.github.com/simondec/37608882518721e6d28b) using default UITableViewCells:

Comment: Well I just tried `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` but nothing happen. I think it might be the constrain conflict.. Still thank you for your answer. Just feel so frustrated about all these cell row height things.

Comment: @Edward90s I updated my answer with a new hint:  It seems like you also need to set ```estimatedRowHeight```.  I added a link toward a working example.

Comment: yes your code works! There's something need to be modified to get things done. Delete this line `[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];`. Thanks!

Comment: @Edward90s I was not sure whether you were using a UIViewController or a UITableViewController.  I made my example for the former, but I updated it for the latter.  Is there anything missing from my answer to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Rufel. I fixed this by registering nib files with a custom UITableViewCell class in which I set the `numberOfLines = 0` on my textLabel, and that that works well. `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `estimatedRowHeight` are needed also to enable self sizing. The thing that confuse me is I did exactly as Luke did in the WWDC session 226 but came with a different result. And you're right about ` [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];`, for me I used a UITableViewController instead.

Comment: @Edward90s you're very welcome!  If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted to help others facing the same issue.

Comment: yeah I tried but, well I'm new here with poor reputation, so I'm simply unable to vote up your anwser

Comment: @Edward90s: To mark an answer as accepted, all you have to do is click on the hollow checkmark button under the answer's upvote count.  That will tag your "issue" as resolved.  You should be able to do it no matter your reputation. :)